# Is it safe to use an egg incubator to grow bacterial cultures?

Tags: microbiology

I've been using a small egg incubator to grow environmental bacteria in petri dishes. I always wear gloves and glasses when I handle the plates and do Gram staining. How likely is it that bacteria grown on dish could become airborne when I open the incubator or the dishes themselves?

Comment: the type of egg incubator would be important that is a vast variety which produce very different risks.

Answer (score 3):

A good practice to **minimize the contamination** of a Petri dish and of the external environment is **by never completely removing the lid** of the Petri dish: to access the content of the Petri dish with an inoculation loop, lift the lid on one side, slowly: just high enough for the inoculation loop to get in, get some of the content, and get out.

Answer (score 2):

if you keep the petri dishes covered there will be little or no contamination and there will be negligible e coli aerosol when you open the incubator. as mentioned by @MartinKivana don't open the plates, esp near the incubator.  In a sterile environment is better...

if you don't keep the petri dishes covered your experiment will be ruined.

you can wipe it down with bleach once in a while...

so that about covers it.